# Handling errors with RxJava and MVVM pattern in Android

Tags: android, mvvm, rx-java

I'm developing application wherein I want to use MVVM pattern. Currently, all events from xml are handled by the activity which pass them next to ViewModel. E.g. user clicks login button, the event is handled by activity; now the activity call view model's method, inside this method I'm calling RxFirebase (Rx wrapper on Firebase) method which returns Observable, subscribe to them and return it; in view I'm again subscribe to this observable for doing UI update. This situation is presented below.

My question is if this approach is correct? In my opinion, the better solution is to handle the error in ViewModel, but how then I can update UI? One of the solutions is to create interface, e.g. ShowMessageListener, next pass it to ViewModel and use to show message, but I prefer harness RxJava to this.

**View method:**

```
public void onLoginClick(View view) {
    mBinding.clProgress.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    mViewModel.onLoginClick().subscribe(authResult -> {
            mBinding.clProgress.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            startAnotherActivity();
        }, throwable -> {
            mBinding.clProgress.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            if (throwable instanceof FirebaseApiNotAvailableException) {
                Snackbar.make(mBinding.getRoot(), R.string.google_play_services_unavilable, Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } else {
                Snackbar.make(mBinding.getRoot(), throwable.getMessage(), Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
}
```

**ViewModel method:**

```
public Observable<AuthResult> onLoginClick() {
    Observable<AuthResult> observable = RxFirebaseAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(mAuth, mEmail.get(), mPassword.get());
    observable.subscribe(authResult -> {
        //save user
    }, throwable -> {
        //handle error
    });
    return observable;
}
```

Comment: Hope the answer fit your needs, if not just comment, ill extend the sample in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your answer is almost correct except that you should really seperate View and (Business)-Logic. This would be the attempt if you use databinding which is **highly recommend** when using Architecture Components.

That means that everything which updates the UI should be in your View, everything which is not relevant for the view should be in the ViewModel.

That means that you can pass your ViewModel to your Layout, which has a onClick and call the Method in the ViewModel. Example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout ..>
    <data><variable name="viewModel" type="YourVm" /></data>
    <Button onClick="@{viewModel::onButtonClick}  
</layout>
```

Now you can handle the onClick inside your ViewModel like

```
public void onClick(View view) {
Log.d("Click", "My Button was clicked");
}
```

If you "really" want to observe for errors from your View you could either Create an ObservableBoolean which is set to True onec there's an error and subscribe for changes. You can put it inside the ViewModel like:

```
public final ObservableBoolean observableError = new ObservableBoolean();
public void onClick(...) { observableError.set(true); }
```

Now you can observe the Boolean inside your View

```
yourViewModel.obserableError.observe(this, result -> {
     // do your error stuff 
});
```

If you don't use Databinding it's almost the same except that you pass a ClickListener to the Button.

Means that you listen for the OnClick in your View, call the "processing"-method in your ViewModel and update the ObservableBoolean if an error occured. Since your a Listening for changes you can process the SnackBar stuff inside your View.

Snackbar and everything which involves the view should really be seperated from the ViewModel except a navigator. In this case you should create WeakReferences to avoid leaks.

Take care that the ObservableBoolean is **NOT** part of RxJava. It's part of Architecture Components.

If you want to solve it using RxJava you could create a PublishSubject in your ViewModel like:

Viewmodel.java

```
 public final PublishSubject<String> ps = PublishSubject.create<>()
 public void onClick(...) { ps.next("my evil error string"); }
```

And finally Observe it in your view

```
myViewModel.ps.subscribe( data -> {...}, error -> { ... } )
```

Take care that you dispose your RxJava Subscriptions in `onCleared()` which is in your ViewModel interface.

*Edit*: I haven't tested the code since i have only Kotlin Projects at the moment but should work in java.

Found an issue in your code that you didnt validate if mBinding is null. This may be null since you subscribe for changes and try to create the SnackBar in the View which may be disposed already. Always use `if (mBinding != null) Snackbar.snackysnacky(..)`

Comment: I'm using data binding now. The reason why I handle events in View is that I want to make ViewModel platform independent. I have read about two approaches - the first solution is used by me - handlers interface implemented by activity and used by xml, the second one is yours in which method view parameter should be ignored and never used.

Anyway - thanks for your answer, I will be using Architecture Components Observable fields in my application!

Comment: Since it's not really mvvm in android you can either put the handlers in your ViewModel and call them in your layout (since this can be tested and called without view aswell) or you can pass a view to your layout and create the handlers in your view.

Comment: I have one more question - is there any reason for using PublishSubject or Architecture Component's Observables?
I know that Architecture Components are in alpha stage, so currently RxJava seems as better solution?

Comment: Even if they are in Alpha Stage they are almost stable and ready to use in productive apps. And yes, there's a reason. Since Architecture Observables cares about the ViewModel state and dispose if the ViewModel is disposed you dont get any leaks. Using RxJava means that you always take care that you dispose in onCleared() to avoid memory leaks

Comment: It make sens. Thanks for you advice!

Comment: You'r welcome. I use MVVM+LiveData+Room in a very large project and i dont have any problems (Java AND now ported to Kotlin)